# Wordpress: only show posts for specific category IF post = comments allowed

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, comments

I have a page that displays certain posts from a certain category, in this case category 33:

```
  <?php $top_query = new WP_Query('cat=33'); ?>
  <?php while($top_query->have_posts()) : $top_query->the_post(); ?>
```

How Can I specify that the posts returned should only be ones that have comments enabled?.
I have tried wrapping it in:

```
<?php if(comments_open()) : ?>
```

Hover that needs to be used within the loop :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the [wordpress database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) the post status is saved in the `$wpdb->posts` table in the `comment_status` column. Try passing this variable to [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) also like this:

```
<?php $top_query = new WP_Query( array('cat'=>33, 'comment_status'=>'open'); ?>
<?php while($top_query->have_posts()) : $top_query->the_post(); ?>
```

this should do it.